# How to create a custom view for a sql table using STRAGG()

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a custom view for the following table:

### TABLE "ORG"

- NAME, VARCHAR2
- PLACE, NUMBER
- PLACE_PRIMARY, NUMBER

(PLACE and PLACE_PRIMARY refer to a foreign key in another table)

And the view basically combines any row from ORG that has the same name and combines their PLACE into a list, but I'm confused how to do the WHERE clause.  Here is what I have so far:

```
  SELECT org.name, 
         STRAGG(refdata.display_name) place, 
         STRAGG(refdata.display_name) place_primary
    FROM table_organization org, 
         table_reference_data refdata
   WHERE org.name = org.name 
GROUP BY org.name 
ORDER BY org.name;
```

UPDATE:

I got the following to pull a list of the PLACE column:

```
SELECT org.name, stragg(DISTINCT org.place)
    FROM table_organization org, table_reference_data refdata
GROUP BY org.name;
```

The problem is that it currently only shows the foreign key and not the string value from the table_reference_data.

Comment: Reference: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336, and: http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11591.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to change this:

```
SELECT org.name, stragg(DISTINCT org.place)
    FROM table_organization org, table_reference_data refdata
GROUP BY org.name;
```

to

```
SELECT org.name, stragg(DISTINCT refdata.stringvalue)
    FROM table_organization org
    JOIN table_reference_data refdata ON refdata.keycol = org.place
GROUP BY org.name;
```

(changing refdata.keycol and refdata.stringvalue to use the real column names).

Comment: That works!  But I just realized there's a mistake in my original code.  The org.place reference actually points back to the ORG table as an organization can be inside another organization type!!!!  I'll try to figure out how to call the same table twice.....